# Yii2 link 3 different tables together and use a field in one of those fields

Tags: php, yii2

I have an agents table with fields (id, name)

I have an agent_aggregators table with fields (agent_id,aggregator_id)

I have a transactions table with field (agent_id)

Aggregators table is connected to agents table through the agent_id.

Transactions table has an agent_id field.

Now in my transactions view i have a index.php i want to display the name of the aggregator that did a particular transactions

Transaction view/ index.php

```
['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
[
   'attribute' => 'agent.aggregators.name',
   label' => 'Aggregator\'s  Name',
]
```

Transactions model:

```php
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;


class Transactions extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'transactions';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [



        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'ID' => 'ID',
        ];
    }



    public function getAgent()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Agents::className(), ['ID' => 'agent_id']);
    }

}
```

Aggregator model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

class AgentsAggregators extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'agents_aggregators';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [

        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'agent_id' => 'Agent ID',

        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getAgent()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Agents::className(), ['ID' => 'agent_id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getAggregator()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Agents::className(), ['ID' => 'aggregator_id']);
    }


}
```

Agents model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

class Agents extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'agents';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */

        public function rules()
    {
        return [

        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'ID' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Agent\'s Name',
        ];
    }


    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getAgentsAggregators()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AgentsAggregators::className(), ['agent_id' => 'ID']);
    }


    public function getAggregators()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Agents::className(), ['ID' => 'aggregator_id'])->viaTable('agents_aggregators', ['agent_id' => 'ID']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getAgents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Agents::className(), ['ID' => 'agent_id'])->viaTable('agents_aggregators', ['aggregator_id' => 'ID']);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the three models?

Comment: @anfen i just updated my question. I removed sensitive part of my code and left just enough code to deal with the probelem

Comment: I think you forgot to add the rules and/or attributes of models. I suggest you to create models with Gii
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-gii

Answer (score 0):

Your relationship between transactions and agents tables is One to Many kind of relationship. However, agents to aggregators is Many to many. So you cannot get a single aggregator (in strict sense) but it will be always a collection of aggregators (may have one element though). That this code should illustrate what you are trying to do.

Let me know in comments if I misunderstood your question.

```
[
   'label' => "Aggregator's  Name",
   'format' =>'ntext',
    'value' => function($model)
    {
        $aggrs = $model->agent->aggregators;
        return implode('\n', $aggrs);
    }
]
```